# Screen lock disables color correction profile

Tags: gnome, gdm, i3-wm, color-management

I calibrated my monitor using a colorimeter and the color tab in Gnome settings.

The color on the screen looks good until the screen turns off (automatically after some time). When the screen starts dimming the color suddenly changes as if the color calibration was disabled.

When unlocking the screen the color is still wrong, and I have to go to the color tab in Gnome settings to disable and enable the color correction of the monitor to get back the correct colors.

This doesn't seem to happen if I lock the screen manually. (Is it linked to the dimming when it locks automatically?)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10, `kernel 5.8.0-40-generic`, `nvidia-driver-460`, `regolith-desktop-standard` (i3wm), `regolith-compositor-xcompmgr`.

Is this some sort of bug or have I overlooked something?